# passing bundle/ContentValues between forms and the difference between ContentValues between bundle

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

i have tried passing `ContentValues` to insert to a database.

```
public long createEntry(String name, String description) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

    }
```

this method works. but now i wanna know how do i pass it to other forms through intent. i only know to use intent to transfer views/forms but not how to pass data.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("lol","hello");
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.oil:
            Intent i = new Intent("com.gtxradeon.brands.FirstBrandActivity");
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.android:
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this, FirstBrandActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

and finally, what's the difference between Bundles and ContentValues.. i have tried reading on google tutorials for android but it got me more confused.

Answer (score 4):

`ContentValue`s are used to update/insert data into a permanent storage data structures like SQLite databases. It is important to use `ContentValue`s to prevent SQL injections.

Bundles in the other hand are used to pass data among `Activities` using `Intent`s. For example,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", "John Doe");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

You can retrieve the `Bundle` in the next `Activity` by doing:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String string = bundle.getString("name");
```

Another more common way of achieving the same result is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("name", "John Doe");
```

Then on the `Activity` you get the `Intent` by:

```
Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
String name = receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 2):

In general content values are used in database like Sql.
My suggestion to pass values from one activity to other in s ways.

1.Bundle.
2.Shared Preferences.
3.static variable.

Bundle:-

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("key","value you need to retrieve in another activity");
b.putString("name","nikhil");
Intent i=new Intent(ctx,Youractivityname.class);
i.putExtras(b); 
StartActiviyt(i);
```

In your next activity page

```
Intent get=getIntent();
Bundle b=get.getExtras();
 if(b!=null){
 String name=b.getString("name");
}
```

SharedPreferences:-

```
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;
   sp = getSharedPreferences("enter", MODE_PRIVATE);
                     edit = sp.edit();
                     edit.putString("username", nikhil);

                     edit.commit();
```

In the next activity

```
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("enter", MODE_PRIVATE);
    user.setText(sp.getString("username", "default value"));
```

Static variable:-
In firstactivity:-

```
static String s="nikhil";
```

In next activity:-

```
String n=firstactivity.s
```